# How do I "print" a list inside another list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, redirect, scaffold

I started using rails today and got into a problem.

I created three classes: Item, Requisito and Video. The last two has a scaffold item:references

Then I pointed the Item class to the other two items.

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :materia
  has_many :requisitos
  has_many :videos
end
```

Now, I want to print everything in.

item.name

item.requisito.type

item.video.link

So I made this code.

```
<h1>Listing items</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Materia</th>
    <th>Requisitos</th>
    <th>Videos</th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
</tr>

<% @items.each do |item| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= item.name %></td>
    <td>
        <% @items.requisitos.each do |requisito|%>
    <%= requisito.type %>
    <br>
    <% end %>
    </td>
<td>
    <% @items.videos.each do |video|%>
    <%= video.link %>
    <br>
    <% end %>
    </td>
   <td><%= link_to 'Show', item %></td>
   <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_item_path(item) %></td>
   <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', item, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Item', new_item_path %>
```

As you can see, I just gave a shot on how the code should be... and as I expected, it was wrong. Can someone please point out the right way to make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your nested `each` blocks should be iterating over `item.requisitos` not `@items.requisitos` (same for videos). So like this:

```
<% item.requisitos.each do |requisito|%>
  <%= requisito.type %>
  <br>
<% end %>
```

and

```
<% item.videos.each do |video|%>
  <%= video.link %>
  <br>
<% end %>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Helped? It solved the question in 10 seconds xD, Thanks a lot!